# Transfer UV map and 3D data between objects

Tags: modeling

[image]
Can someone help me transfer the uv map and the 3d model of the object from the right to the left?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gORp5LC9xZk
this can probably help you with that